# Why is $y(n)=x(n)-x(n−1)+x(n-2)$ a low-pass filter?

Tags: filters, frequency-response, digital-filters

I know that it's a low-pass FIR filter with impulse response of length equal to $3$, but I don't know how to explain exactly why it's low-pass.

Comment: Might want to revert title to original; there was room for confusion hence the earlier comment.

Answer (score 4):

Observe the magnitude of frequency response (rescaled to 0 to 1):

[image]

where

$$
\begin{align}
H(\omega) 
&= e^{-j 0\omega} - e^{-j 1\omega} + e^{-j 2\omega} \\
&= 1 - e^{-j 1\omega} + e^{-j 2\omega} \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
following the time-shift property:

$$ 
x(t - t_0) \Leftrightarrow e^{-j t_0 \omega} X(\omega) \tag{2}
$$

Though it isn't particularly good, it's more "high-pass" than "low-pass" if we must choose. Example on White Gaussian Noise:

[image]

We can see the frequency response for all possible $t_0$ up to $x$'s length:

[image]

The more terms we add following the pattern, the better the high-passing. (Note: plots use DFT with dc bin at sample 0 and Nyquist at 16, so toward center = higher freqs).

---

#### Explanation

$x(n) - x(n - 1) + x(n + 2)$ is simply a transformation of $x$. Whether it's "lowpass" or "highpass" is a *frequency-domain description*, so we describe the transform directly in frequency domain.

Here we're simply adding time-shifted and sign-flipped version of $x$ to itself. In frequency domain, this is described by $(2)$. So we have:

$$
\begin{align}
x(n) 
& \Leftrightarrow X(\omega) \\
x(n) - x(n - 1)
& \Leftrightarrow X(\omega) - e^{-j 1 \omega}X(\omega) \\
x(n) - x(n - 1) + x(n - 2)
& \Leftrightarrow X(\omega) - e^{-j 1 \omega}X(\omega) 
+ e^{-j 2 \omega}X(\omega) \\
& ...
\end{align}
$$

To see the effect this has on any $x$, independent of $x$, we simply divide it out - which gives the *frequency response*:

$$
\begin{align}
H(\omega) 
&= Y(\omega) / X(\omega) \\
&= \left( X(\omega) \cdot (1 - e^{-j1\omega} + e^{-j2\omega})\right) / X(\omega) \\
&= \boxed{1 - e^{-j1\omega} + e^{-j2\omega}}
\end{align}
$$

and thus, for any $x$ with frequencies $X(\omega)$, the effect of the transform is $X(\omega) \rightarrow H(\omega)X(\omega)$.

---

#### Code

Available at [Github](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/StackExchangeAnswers/blob/main/SignalProcessing/Q76636%20-%20filters%20-%20Why%20is%20x(n)%20-%20x(n%20-%20%201)%20%2B%20x(n%20%2B%202)%20lowpass/main.py).

Comment: @OverLordDragon: Nice answer and I follow how you got $H(\omega)$ but I didn't follow where you used the time shift property ? Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds Time-shift + linearity: $x(t-1) \Leftrightarrow e^{-j1 \omega} X(\omega)$, so $\mathcal{F}(\text{stuff} + x(t-1)) = \mathcal{F}(\text{stuff}) + e^{-j1 \omega} X(\omega)$.

Comment: I'm sorry for my denseness but are you saying that you are using that relation to calculate the last animated plot where you plot the result for different values of $t_{0}$. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @markleeds Right, it's just $x(t-2), x(t-3), ...$ and signs alternated, $+, -, ...$, which corresponds to $+e^{...2...} - e^{...3...} ...$ when taken as impulse response. Impulse response is $H(\omega) = Y(\omega) / X(\omega)$ and we factor the common $X(\omega)$ in $Y(\omega) = X(\omega) e^{...0...} - X(\omega) e^{...1...} ...$ which cancels and just leaves $e^{...}$'s.

Comment: Thanks. Your patience and explanation is much appreciated. And very kool plot.