# In time series analysis, is taking a multi-period difference equivalent to a band-pass filter?

Tags: filters, frequency-response, time-series

For time series, a simple high-pass filter is obtained by subtracting the previous value from each value:

$y(n) = x(n) - x(n-1)$

If I take a multi-period difference:

$y(n) = x(n) - x(n - a)$ where $a > 1$

Is this equivalent to a band-pass filter which attenuates frequencies significantly above and below $1 / a$? If not, how can it be described in terms of high/low/band-pass filters?

Comment: "Explanation" [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/76638/50076) might help.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Thanks for the link. I ran your code and got what appears to be a filter that selects frequencies that are a multiple of 1/a. Is there a name for this type of filter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are describing is two cases of a more general form of a [Comb Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_filter) (I encourage you to go through the link, but I'll adapt to your particular case here):
$$y(n) = x(n) + \alpha x(n-K) $$
with $K$ the delay in samples, and $\alpha$ the scaling factor applied to the delayed signal. In your case, you have $\alpha = -1$, which gives you $$y(n) = x(n) - x(n-K)$$

---

To figure out what kind of filter this is, let's move to the frequency domain:

1. Take the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform and derive the **transfer function**:

\begin{align*} 
Y(z) &= X(z) - z^{-K}X(z)= X(z)(1-z^{-K})\\\\
\implies  H(z) &= \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = 1 - z^{-K}
\end{align*}

2. Substitute $z = e^{j\omega}$ to get the **frequency response**:
   $$H(\omega) = 1 - e^{-j\omega K}$$
   At this point, you can note that for $\omega = 0$, $H(\omega) = 0$ so you can rule out "low-pass".
3. Let's go further, and compute the **magnitude response**:

\begin{align*}
\vert H(\omega) \vert &= \vert 1 - e^{-j\omega K} \vert \\\\
&= \vert 1 - \cos{(\omega K)} + j\sin{(\omega K)} \vert \\\\
&= \sqrt{1 - 2 \cos{(\omega K)} + \cos^2{(\omega K}) + \sin^2{(\omega K})}\\\\
&= \sqrt{1 - 2 \cos{(\omega K)} + 1}\\\\
&= \sqrt{2 - 2 \cos{(\omega K)}}\\\\
&= \sqrt{2\vphantom{1 - \cos{(\omega K)}}} \cdot \sqrt{1 - \cos{(\omega K)}}
\end{align*}

4. Let's now analyze the magnitude response:

- $\vert H(\omega) \vert$ is periodic (since you have a cosine term).
- $\vert H(\omega) \vert = 0$ for $\omega = 2\pi / K$ since $ \cos{(2\pi)} = 1$, but ALSO for $\omega = 4\pi / K$ since $\cos{(4\pi)} = 1$
  As a matter of fact, $\vert H(\omega) \vert = 0$ (the **nulls**) for every integer $k$ such that:
  $$\omega = \frac{2\pi k}{K}$$
- Similarly, the maxima (the **peaks**) happen when $\cos{(\omega K)} = -1$, at $k$ such that:
  $$\omega = \frac{\pi k}{K}$$
  At these peaks, $\vert H(\omega) \vert = 2$

---

The resulting magnitude response looks like a comb, hence the term **Comb Filter**.

Here are a few examples for different values of $K$ on a logarithmic scale, restricting ourselves to the normalized Nyquist frequency $\pi$, and normalizing by the peak value ($\vert H(\omega) \vert = 2$) so that the maxima fall at $0\,\texttt{dB}$:

[image]